# Proving that 31123319 is the largest number with a self-accounting property (A047841)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

22 is special because it contains the number of its numbers. The next smallest number with this self-accounting property (see [A047841](https://oeis.org/A047841)) is 10213223. What is the largest such number?

I've figured out the numbers work in pairs, so the number must have an even number of digits, be at least 8 digits and that within each pair, 0 can never be first. Ex. 1002 has a 2, so there can't be 0 2's in the number. Beyond these parameters, I'm not sure how else to approach this problem. I'm was thinking that maybe something could be done with permutations and combinations, since the numbers work as pairs and there are some conditions, but I'm not sure how I would actually do this.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: This is [A047841](http://oeis.org/A047841), next one is $10311233$.  Apparently there are $109$ of them.

Comment: How exactly is the "number of numbers" defined ?

Comment: It means self-accounting. 22 has 2 2's, so it has the numbers of its numbers. 10213223 has 1 0, 2 1's, 3 2's and 2 3's so it has the number of its numbers. Each pair (ex. the first 2 digits, 10 for 10213223) works this way, with the first digit (1 in , this case) telling you how many of the second digit (0) are in the number.

Comment: Note that 101112213141516171819 has an odd number of digits since there are 11 ones.

Comment: The $191817161514132211110$ is greater, the OEIS you link to has additional restriction you do not mention anywhere (the counted digits appear in increasing order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method of attack - illustrated for 8 digit numbers, where no particular digit occurs more than $9$ times. Initially I will assume that the order of the pairs is irrelevant.

Let the number be $aAbBcCdD$. Then $a+b+c+d=8$ with each of $a,b,c,d$ being non-zero.

For the 8 digit number to have initial digit at least $3$, the possibilities for $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are $\{5,1,1,1\}$, $\{4,2,1,1\}$,$\{3,3,1,1\}$ or $\{3,2,2,1\}$.

Now apply the self-accounting property to each possibility:-

$\{5,1,1,1\}=\{A,A,A,A\}$ Impossible

$\{4,2,1,1\}=\{A,A,A,B\}$ Impossible

$\{3,3,1,1\}=\{A,A,B,B\}$ Solved by $A=3,B=1$. Eg. $31331819$

$\{3,2,2,1\}=\{A,A,B,C\}$ Solved by $A=2,B=3,C=1$. Eg. $21322319$ when the initial digit is not $3$ if the counted digits are put into ascending order.